# How do I make an expandable skype popup?

Tags: skype

I was switching between skype, as a person replied, and twitch on my phone and wasn't paying particularly close attention to the switch at one point and magically there was a little skype icon on my twitch app I could move around and expand into the skype convo I was going to and then collapse again without ever causing the stream I was watching to go away.

Problem is I'm not entirely sure what I did to do that and I would really like to be able to have that open anytime I'm doing something in particular on my phone and chatting in skype at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that with some apps, Skype included, if you swipe down and to the left in the app from the corner it'll make the app into a little popup that just sits on your phone till you do something with it.